# Convergence in probability and expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $\mathbb EX$ exist and $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$. How to prove that $\mathbb EX_n → \mathbb EX$ then and only when $\mathbb E| X_n - X | → 0$?

Comment: If $X_n \to X$ almost surely, then this follows from Scheffe's lemma, see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83208/36150). To get the result for convergence in probability you can use a similiar reasoning as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/920227/36150).

Comment: @saz Scheffe's Lemma does not apply here. In the post you have quoted it is given that $E|X_n| \to E|X|$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah right, I missed that the OP is not assuming convergence of $L^1$ norms, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $[-1,1]$ with the measure $P(A)=\frac {\lambda(A)} 2$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Let $X_n(x)=n^{2} xI_{(-\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n)}(x)$, and $X\equiv0$. Then $EX_n =EX=0$ for all $n$ and $X_n \to X$ almost surely, hence in probability. But $E|X_n|=1$ for all $n$.